# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot with 4g deocding enabled

Tags: boot, 16.04

**The Setup:**

- Dual INTEL® XEON® PROCESSOR E5-2660 V4
- Dual Quadro P4000
- Supermicro X10DAI
- 128 GB RAM
- EVGA 850W PS
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Samsung 850EVO 500GB

**Install**

Fresh Install.

**Problem:**

Whenever I try to load Ubuntu, the BIOS will boot and post; but Ubuntu will not boot (just a black screen) if I have 4G decoding enabled. I need 4G decoding enabled because I want to use 2 GPU's; and the BIOS will alert me that it has run out of PCI resources. Supermicro told me to prevent this, enagle 4G decoding. If I use 2 GPU's with 4G decoding enabled, Ubuntu won't load. However, if I use 1 GPU without 4G decoding enabled, then everything works fine.

**Next Steps**

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I don't see anybody having problems with 4g decoding enabled.

Edit:

Even with the Nvidia Drivers (375 and 378 were both tried on fresh installs), Ubuntu still will not boot.

Comment: I think you need Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Having same issue on Asus z270-P and GTX 1060